# React Native navigation reset does not work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have two stack in my application

- Tab Navigator (main stack)
- Stack Navigator (app stack)

Stack Navigator elements

- Home Screen
- Detail Screen
- Login Screen

Tab Navigator elements

- Home Screen (Stack Navigor)
- Economy News
- Politic News
- Social News

I want to go Detail screen from Economy News, Politic News and Social News because I render the all news in these screens and when the user click the any new, must go to the Detail screen with new which clicked. I used navigate('Home', {screen: 'Detail', params: {id: new.ID}});
But it always render the previous new detail.

Also I tried

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'Home',
      },
      {
        name: 'Detail',
        params: {
          id: new.ID,
        },
      },
    ],
  }),
);
```

But still it does not work I need to help about this issue I have tried so many things but always render the previous screen detail.

Comment: can you post more code because navigate('Home', {screen: 'Detail', params: {id: new.ID}}); should reset your param

Comment: of course i will write an answer i will share there

Answer (score 1):

That's my home stack nav

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  headerMode="none"
  transitionConfig={transitionConfig}
>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Detail"
    component={DetailScreen}
    initialParams={props.route.params}
  />
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

and that one is my main tab nav

```
     <Tab.Navigator
        tabBar={props => <Footer {...props} />}
        transitionConfig={transitionConfig}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={StackNavigator} />
        <Tab.Screen name="EconomyNews" component={ContentScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="PoliticNews" component={ContentScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="SocialNews" component={ContentScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

I want to go to Detail Screen from EconomyNews, PoliticNews or SocialNews screens with new values like id but it always render the previous screen

Comment: all looks fine add DetailScreen full code and ContentScreen as well

Comment: i can't share all code cause when i share the moderator is deleting my answer but i can share little bit.

Comment: `const Detail = React.memo(props => { const [content, setContent] = useState(null); const dispatch = useDispatch(); const contentProps = useSelector(state => state.contentReducer); const { loading, error, detail } = contentProps; useEffect(() => {function fetchData() {dispatch(getDetail({endpoint: `URL`}));}fetchData();}, []);return (<Container><Image source={{uri:'URL'}}/><View style={styles.content_container}><Title>{content.title}</Title><OverView style={styles.content}>{content.overview}</OverView></Container>);});`

Comment: Content Screen > `const Content = React.memo(props => {const { item, navigation } = props; return ( <View> <TouchableWithoutFeedback /n onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Home', {screen: 'Detail', params: {id: item.ID}});}}> <Container> <Image source={{uri: 'URL'}}/> <Title>{item.original_title} ({item.title})</Title> <OverView numberOfLines={5}>{item.overview}</OverView> </Container></View>); });`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to follow your code but I don't see that you are using in Detail component the id so is imposible that you have another data.
You don't need memo in your case ...

```
const Detail = props => { 
const [content, setContent] = useState(null); 
const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
const contentProps = useSelector(state => state.contentReducer); 
const { loading, error, detail } = contentProps; 
const URL = `URL/${props.navigation?.route?.params?.id}`
useEffect(() => {
function fetchData() {
dispatch(getDetail({endpoint: URL}));}
fetchData();
}, [dispatch, props.navigation?.route?.params?.id]);
return (<Container><Image source={{uri:'URL'}}/><View style={styles.content_container}><Title>{content.title}</Title><OverView style={styles.content}>{content.overview}</OverView></Container>);};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the id in url which in fetch function. I use it to get data from service that's why i did not write the exactly url. The main goal is open the Detail Screen with reset. I also tried another way today and it has not been worked;

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
const Content = (props => {
   const _nav = useNavigation();
   const goToRoute = () => {
      _nav.reset({
         index: 1,
         routes: [
         {
           name: 'Home',
         },
         {
           name: 'Detail',
           params: {
             id: item.ID,
           },
         },
      ],
   });
 };
});
```

Comment: could you make a snack because you don't need use reset. To reset the params something is wrong and I can't see it. Here is a template with react navigation v5 ready https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/41a9b3

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/ye!rF6rv6 this is my snack code similar

Comment: In this expo all working u get fresh param all time.

Comment: I have fixed the issue :) thank you for all help. I just realized I was keep fresh my params but was not React state, I changed a little code about my params. While i get the params i assigned the react state and i started to use these react state variables in my useEffect function and it works. It's all about the react statement and virtual dom. I was not understand this issue. Now it works :D :D